# Cannot update. Database or object is read-only

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, excel, oledbconnection

In my MVC3 Razor project , i have upload one excel sheet and save that in my project Folder. I need to read the values inside the excel. To do that i just create OLedbConnection.i got the error "Cannot update.  Database or object is read-only." while executing the line  dbConnection.Open();

Controller:

```
        string fp="@"+Session["FilePathFinal"].ToString();
        DataTable fooData = new DataTable();
        OleDbConnection dbConnection =
          new OleDbConnection
            (@"Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;"
             + @"Data Source='"+fp+"';"
             + @"Extended Properties=""Excel 8.0;""");
        dbConnection.Open();
```

the fp is filepath. filepath contains the value                                    `@D:\MVC\Admin\Import.Admin\App_Data\ImportFileHome\Baby needs.csv`

how to get out of this issue. Any help???

Note: My excel file is Excel 2013

Comment: Not sure why you have the `@` symbol at the beginning of your file name. Try it without, i.e. `string fp = Session["FilePathFinal"].ToString();`

Answer (score -1):

For CSV try this:

```
OleDbConnection conn = new OleDbConnection
               ("Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OleDb.4.0; Data Source = " +
                 Path.GetDirectoryName(FileName) +
                 "; Extended Properties = \"Text;HDR=YES;FMT=Delimited\"");
```

Comment: Though the file name in the question ends in `.csv` it is not clear, how this answer should help resolving the issue.